# Phalcon\Mvc\Models - model relationship and caching

Tags: php, phalcon

There's this in Phalcon docs:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#taking-advantage-of-relationships.

Suppose I have a code like this:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasMany("id", "RobotsParts", "robots_id");
}

/**
 * Return the related "robots parts"
 *
 * @return \RobotsParts[]
 */
public function getRobotsParts($parameters=null)
{
    return $this->getRelated('RobotsParts', $parameters);
}
```

I wonder what is the best approach to cache what "**->getRelated()**" lookup is producing? Meaning, it should not go to database if it gets called more than once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have defined your cache mechanism in the service container, you can do this:

```
public function getRobotsParts($parameters=null)
{
    $di  = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
    $key = 'cache_robots_parts_' . $this->id;

    $cache = $di->cache->get($key);

    if (null == $cache) {
        $results = $this->getRelated('RobotsParts', $parameters);
    } else {
        $results = $cache;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an obvious thing to do. I was wondering whether $obj->_modelsManager has built-in caching capability.

Comment: A caching strategy exists but it gets released after the request is terminated. For more information you can have a look at this http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models-cache.html#caching-related-records

Answer (score 0):

It may be written on the short way:

```
public function getRobotsParts($parameters=null)
{
    $parameters['cache'] = array(
        'lifetime' => 123,
        'key'      => 'cache_robots_parts_' . $this->id,
    );

    return $this->getRelated('RobotsParts', $parameters);
}
```

Or more short, if `$parameters['cache']` set in method, which caused this